# Where is the script for alias command in Linux?

Tags: bash, alias

I want to add an argument to bash alias script so that i can just run

```
alias -p l='ls -l'
```

and it would get added to my .zshrc permenantly. But i am unable to locate the shell script for alias.

I tried `whereis alias`, but with no luck. even `man alias` shows alias has no entry.

I looked in `/usr/bin, /usr/share/local/bin` but with no luck. Can anyone pointout the location?

EDIT:
I have also tried looking in all possible paths by `ls $(echo $PATH| tr ':' '\n') | grep alias`

Comment: alias is bash builtin command, like `cd` or `for`, ... Use `man bash`.

Comment: "...to _bash_ alias...", but "...to my _.zshrc_..." Which shell are you running? Or do you really want to configure one shell from the other?

Comment: But how do i edit it to add another argument ?

Comment: You have to manually add it to your `rc` file.  Whether it's `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

Comment: @ilkkachu I am using zsh shell. So, i want to add a corresponding entry in .zshrc

Comment: See the first part of this answer a difference between a built-in and external commands is discussed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202326/72304. It's about `Bash` but it works the same way in `zsh`.

Comment: So, is there no way i can add argument?

Comment: Maybe a work-around could be to use shell functions. Can it be done them.

Comment: @Infinity:  You need to do more research about what an alias is.  Also read my comment above.

Comment: @Jesse_b I read about shell bulletins as suggested by @Arkdiusz\ Drabczyk and i know adding it to my rc file would work. But what if i want to add aliases dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean dynamically?   The only way to make them persistent is to add it to one of your shell config files.

Comment: @Jesse_b By dynamically i meant like whever i write `alias -p l='ls'`, ii automatically goes into .zshrc so that i will not need to write everytime i open a new shell, and also i dont have to manually add an entry.

Comment: That isn't what dynamic means.  You only have to manually add it to your rc file one time and it will be available every time you open a new shell.  That can be referred to as persistence, not "dynamic"

Comment: @Jesse_b Ok sorry, will take care about that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`alias` is a builtin command, so it doesn't show up as script in any file, or as a function. The `type` command will show this:

```
$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

But you can still override it. A function with the same name will mask the builtin, unless it's explicitly called with the `builtin` builtin.

So, something like this should work:

```
alias() {
    if [ "$1" = "-p" ]; then
        echo "-p was given";
        shift;
    fi;
    builtin alias "$@";
}
```

If you want to print the same alias assignment to a file, you need to be careful to get it quoted right, so that it's usable as input to the shell.

Something like this might do (added right after the `shift` in the function), but do test it: `printf "alias %q\n" "$@" >> ~/my.alias.file`

As for the Bash vs. Zsh issue, I think the above works with both, but I'm not an expert on Zsh.

---

Incidentally, you may also want to note that Bash's `alias` already has a `-p` option `help alias` says:

```
  Options:
    -p        print all defined aliases in a reusable format
```

I don't know if it's any use, since the default behaviour of `alias` without arguments is also to print all aliases in a reusable format.

Comment: There should be `if [ "$1" == "-p" ]; then` instead of `=`. And Thanx this was what i was looking.

Comment: @Infinity, no, it [must](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382003/170373) [not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168284/170373) be `==`.

Comment: there is also `help alias`

Answer (score 2):

Your `alias` command is most likely a shell-builtin, not a script. You can check this using the `type` command:

```
user@host:~$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

To get documentation about the `alias` builtin you would look at the `bash` man page:

```
man bash
```

To make an alias persistent you would normally add the command to one of your Bash profile files - most likely your `~/.bashrc` file, e.g.:

```
user@host:~$ echo "alias l='ls -l'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `zsh` does not support persistent aliases.

If you like persistent aliases, I recommend you to check http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html for an implementation of aliases with persistent availability.

For other shells, aliases can only be written as alias commands inside the related `.*shrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am mainly working with the bash and have my aliases in .bashrc.

It is located in my home directory under /home/myuser/.bashrc