# Can one declare multiple local variables in one line

Tags: bash

Say one have a function/method `foo`. Can one use the `local` keyword to declare multiple variables in one line, or do they have to be separated by one declare statement for each variable?

```
foo()
{
    local x y z
}
```

or

```
foo()
{
    local x
    local y
    local z
}
```

And further:

```
foo()
{
    local -i x -a y  z
}

foo()
{
    local -i x=2 -a y=()  z
}

…
```

or the equivalent one by one line declaration.

---

*Yes. Could test, but for one I can not find any Q/A on this, and second – there might be some hidden caveats*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can.  A possible caveat is [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155) in that you should declare and assign separately.

That being said it will work except for using multiple declare options between the parameters.  Also note that the declare parameters will apply to all variables (in this case `-i`).

## script0:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare a b c
a=foo
b=bar
c=baz

foo () {
    local a=1 b=2 c=3

    echo "From within func:"
    declare -p a
    declare -p b
    declare -p c
}

foo

echo "From outside func:"
declare -p a
declare -p b
declare -p c
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
From within func:
declare -- a="1"
declare -- b="2"
declare -- c="3"
From outside func:
declare -- a="foo"
declare -- b="bar"
declare -- c="baz"
```

---

## script1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i a -a b c
a=foo
b=(bar)
c=baz

foo () {
    local -i a=1 -a b=(2) c=3

    echo "From within func:"
    declare -p a
    declare -p b
    declare -p c
}

foo

echo "From outside func:"
declare -p a
declare -p b
declare -p c
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 3: declare: `-a': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 9: local: `-a': not a valid identifier
From within func:
declare -i a="1"
declare -ai b=([0]="2")
declare -i c="3"
From outside func:
declare -i a="0"
declare -ai b=([0]="0")
declare -i c="0"
```

Comment: So, if I read your link correctly, the caveat is merely if one assign a value by calling a function or command which might fail.

Comment: @user3342816: Yes and even then it's really only an issue if you wanted to act on `$?` immediately after.  Honestly I usually ignore SC2155 in my scripts because I almost never use `$?` but it's important to know for that reason.

Comment: @user3342816: I would also note my latest update about how the declare option will apply to all parameters being set

Comment: Yes. As with for example `local a -i b c`

Comment: So; multiple of non-type or multiple of same type in one line. No mixing.

Answer (score 7):

To add to @jesse_b's excellent answer. I can confirm this also works (and takes into account the best practise of [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155)):

```
foo()
{
  local x y z
  x=1
  y=2
  z=3
}
```